# Python serial parser only works for 1st set of incoming data

Tags: python, mysql, arduino, serial-port

I am using an arduino with a DHT sensor to take temperature and humidity readings every 15 minutes send the data over an xBee to another xBee connected to a raspberry pi. For testing I am currently sending random numbers.  The code below read, splits and inserts only the first set of data sent, but does not insert any of the data coming in later.

I can tell from the print statements that all data sent are being received and parsed, why aren't the values getting inserted to the DB?

Here is the python script I am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial 
import MySQLdb

#establish connection to MySQL.
dbConn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","mysql_username","mysql_password","database_name") or die ("could not connect to database")
#open a cursor to the database
cursor = dbConn.cursor()

device = '/dev/ttyUSB0' # usually ttyUSB0 or ttyUSB1 for linux, or COM port number for windows
baudrate = 9600



def getSerialData():
 try:
  print "Trying...",device
  arduino = serial.Serial(device, baudrate) 
 except: 
  print "Failed to connect on",device    
 try:
     print "Trying to get data"
     next(arduino)
     data = arduino.readline()  #read the data from the arduino
     pieces = data.split(",")  #split the data by the tab
     print "Data: %s" % data
     print "Piece 1: %s" % pieces[0]
     print "Piece 2: %s" % pieces[1]
     #Here we are going to insert the data into the Database
     try:
       print "Trying insertion..."
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO data (temp,humidity) VALUES (%s,%s)", (pieces[0],pieces[1]))
       dbConn.commit() #commit the insert
       cursor.close()  #close the cursor
     except MySQLdb.IntegrityError:
      print "failed to insert data"
     finally:
      print "closing cursor"
      cursor.close()  #close just in case it failed
      del pieces[:]
 except:
  print "Failed to get data from Arduino!"


val = 0
while val == 0 :
 getSerialData()
```

Output from running the script:

```
Trying... /dev/ttyUSB0
Trying to get data
Data: 140,72

Piece 1: 140
Piece 2: 72

Trying insertion...
closing cursor
Trying... /dev/ttyUSB0
Trying to get data
Data: 94,131

Piece 1: 94
Piece 2: 131

Trying insertion...
closing cursor
Failed to get data from Arduino!
Trying... /dev/ttyUSB0
Trying to get data
Data: 118,56

Piece 1: 118
Piece 2: 56

Trying insertion...
closing cursor
Failed to get data from Arduino!
```

MySQL only gets the first set:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM data;
+----+--------+----------+
| id | temp   | humidity |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | 140.00 |    72.00 |
+----+--------+----------+
```

Code to create my 'data' table:

```
CREATE TABLE `data` ( 
`id` INT(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`temp` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
`humidity` DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`id`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Are you meaning to close the cursor after one use? Try removing the `try` `except` blocks as they are concealing the actual errors you are having.

Comment: Thank you!!!  I commented out the cursor.close() and it is running as expected.

Comment: The real problem is your blanket `try` `except` block is suppressing any errors of any type that may arise in your code, which makes debugging much harder.